# how to effectively use a laptop battery

Tags: macbook, battery-life

Iam using Macbook for my all development needs, i find these days that my battery backup seem to drain very fast (from 5-6 hrs to 3 hrs) is there any effective way its battery so as to retain for longer hours(5-6).

(Please note that Iam using my Macbook with extended monitor in most cases)

Answer (score 1):

The best reference is [Apple's own notebook batteries page](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html), which describes "how to maximize the lifespan and battery life of your Apple notebook."

Topics covered:

- How often they recommend you discharge your battery (once a month)
- Proper long term storage
- Optimal settings for related System Preferences

There's more tips on the [Apple Portables: Tips for maximizing your battery charge](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1446) page.